# Cannot find module 'canvas'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm making a lambda function with serverless framework. The function uses chartjs-node-canvas to generate graphics, I'm using a macbook and it works normally locally. When I deploy to AWS, both directly and through the codebuild, I run into the error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'canvas'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
    "requireStack": [
        "/var/task/index.js",
        "/var/runtime/index.mjs"
    ],
    "stack": [
        "Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)",
        "    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:114:19)",
        "    at fu (/var/task/index.js:1:663)",
        "    at new ln (/var/task/index.js:3:37199)",
        "    at Am (/var/task/index.js:58:1375)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)",
        "    at async Runtime.Dm [as handler] (/var/task/index.js:58:2652)"
    ]
}
```

I've tried using layer and I couldn't, maybe I did it wrong. the chartjs-node-canvas library depends on the canvas library, where the error occurs.

**My serverless.yml:**

```
service: report-infra-costs

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  memorySize: 128
  stage: ${opt:stage, env:STAGE, 'prd'}
  timeout: 500
  region: us-east-1
  versionFunctions: false

  iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
      - ce:GetCostAndUsage
      - ce:DescribeAccount
      - ce:GetDimensionValues
      - organizations:DescribeAccount
    Resource: "*"

functions: 
  sendInfraCosts:
  handler: index.sendReportInfraCosts
  events:
    - schedule: cron(0 8 ? * MON *)

custom: 
  esbuild:
  bundle: true
  minify: true
  exclude: ['aws-sdk']

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline
```

**My buildspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16.x
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install -g serverless
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - serverless deploy --stage ${STAGE} --verbose
```

please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because `node-canvas` relies on system binary files. If you're running your code on Windows or Mac and deploying it to AWS Lambda, which uses Ubuntu, you'll encounter compatibility issues.

To resolve this, you need to create a Lambda layer for `node-canvas`:

1. Utilize the `lambda-layer-canvas-nodejs` layer. Deploy the layer using the template available at [Lambda Layer Canvas Node.js](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:990551184979:applications%7Elambda-layer-canvas-nodejs).
2. Copy the ARN of the layer from the AWS Lambda Console.
3. Update your `serverless.yml` file by adding the layer ARN:

```yaml
service: report-infra-costs

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  memorySize: 128
  stage: ${opt:stage, env:STAGE, 'prd'}
  layers:
    - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<account-id>:layer:canvas-nodejs:1 # Replace with your layer ARN
  timeout: 500
  region: us-east-1
  versionFunctions: false

iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
      - ce:GetCostAndUsage
      - ce:DescribeAccount
      - ce:GetDimensionValues
      - organizations:DescribeAccount
    Resource: "*"

functions: 
  sendInfraCosts:
    handler: index.sendReportInfraCosts
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 8 ? * MON *)

custom: 
  esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: true
    exclude: ['aws-sdk', 'canvas']   # Add canvas here  

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline
```